# What do we want?

Tags: discussion

The Community VP [has asked what our community needs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367906/317948).

I speculate that a lot of people here would tend towards the same kind of answer to that. Feel free to answer this post with suggestions to how we could formulate a community answer, and maybe we can come to a sort of consensus with a good wording.

Comment: The +10 suggests people agree with what *they think* your speculation is. I haven't a clue though, is it possible to add some hints?

Comment: @uhoh +30 on https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368006/317948

Comment: +31 it seems :-)